# MYSQL: Return Counts from Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, return

I am having problems with the following script. I am trying to return a table where recipient counts for both mailings are returned simultaneously. I know that what I have is wrong, but it may give you an idea of what I am looking for.

```
SELECT count( mailing_recipient_id ) AS CountA
                    FROM mailing_recipient
                    WHERE `mailing_id` =(
                                        SELECT mailing_id
                                        FROM mailing
                                        WHERE mailing_name = 'Mailing A' ) 
UNION

SELECT COUNT( mailing_recipient_id ) AS CountB
                    FROM mailing_recipient
                    WHERE `mailing_id` =(
                                        SELECT mailing_id
                                        FROM mailing
                                        WHERE mailing_name = 'Mailing B' );
```

Thank you muchly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to achieve the result you're looking for, as:

```
SELECT
     m.mailing_name ,
    count(mr.mailing_recipient_id)
FROM mailing_recipient mr
INNER JOIN mailing m
ON mr.mailing_id = m.mailing_id
GROUP BY m.mailing_name
ORDER BY m.mailing_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throw them in a subquery:

```
    SELECT SUM(tot.CountA) FROM (

SELECT count( mailing_recipient_id ) AS CountA
                    FROM mailing_recipient
                    WHERE `mailing_id` =(
                                        SELECT mailing_id
                                        FROM mailing
                                        WHERE mailing_name = 'Mailing A' ) 
UNION

SELECT COUNT( mailing_recipient_id ) AS CountA
                    FROM mailing_recipient
                    WHERE `mailing_id` =(
                                        SELECT mailing_id
                                        FROM mailing
                                        WHERE mailing_name = 'Mailing B' ); 

) tot
```

Match the aliases in both of the union queries and SUM the alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(mailing_name = 'Mailing A'), 0) AS CountA,
       IFNULL(SUM(mailing_name = 'Mailing B'), 0) AS CountB
FROM mailing_recipient mr
JOIN mailing m ON mr.mailing_id = m.mailing_id
```